# Añadir css a segundo span dentro de div

Tags: html, css

La duda que tengo hoy es un poco curiosa

Me he topado con el siguiente problema

Tengo dos span dentro de un div y me gustaria añadir css al segundo span sin tener que añadir class o id ¿se puede hacer con child?

```html
<div>
  <span>color por default</span>
  <span>color grey</span>
</div>
```

```js
div>span{
  color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Deberías usar la propiedad `nt:child()`, dónde dentro de los paréntesis se encuentra el número del `span` en tu caso.

El `CSS` quedaría de esta manera:

```
div>span:nth-child(2){
   color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza la propiedad `nth-child()`:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

En tu caso deberias hacer algo así:

```
div span:nth-child(2) {
    color: grey;
}
```

Igualmente te aconsejo que agregues una clase a tu div, para ser mas específico. En ese caso, en el CSS, solo deberás agregar el comando `.tuClase` antes del `span:nth-child(2)`

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes usar:

```
div > sapn:nth-of-type("Aqui escribes la posición del span que quieras cambiar").
```